# R Count and CountDistinct elements of a list

Tags: r, shiny, count, distinct, reactive

I'm facing a little problem: I've used the Tweeter API and I obtained something like:

```
id <- c(1:4)
val <- c(100,150,170,200)
tex <- c("[#price", "#quant]","[#good]","[#good] [#price]")
db <- data.frame(id,val,tex)
```

I would like to count the total number of Hashtags and also the number of the unique hashtags in the simplest way because then I need to put everything inside a reactive database in order to create a dashboard through Shiny.

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `Base-R` this will get all the unique hashtags, you can use `length(  )` to get the count

```
unique(unlist(regmatches(db$tex, gregexpr("#\\w+", db$tex))))

[1] "#price" "#quant" "#good"
```

Edit: 
if you prefer without `#`

```
unique(unlist(regmatches(db$tex, gregexpr("#\\K\\w+", db$tex,perl=T))))
[1] "price" "quant" "good"
```

Comment: I'd suggest `table`. `length(table(...))` would tell us how many unique hashtags, and `sum(table (...))` would tell us how many hashtags overall...

Answer (score 0):

An option with `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
unique(unlist(str_extract_all(db$tex, "#\\w+")))
#[1] "#price" "#quant" "#good"
```

---

Or with `base R` using `strsplit`

```
setdiff(unique(unlist(strsplit(db$tex, "[][ ]+"))), "")
#[1] "#price" "#quant" "#good"
```